# Apache bloodhound installation, AWS host not serving site

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

Following the installation instructions [here](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall) I went through the entire process on an AWS instance. Everything seems to be setup correctly, I can even run BH off the development server using:

```
tracd ./bloodhound/environments/main --port=8000
```

Once I attempt to switch over to using Apache and mod_wsgi though, the supposed URL to be is not serving me anything. Furthermore I'm not receiving any kind of errors in either access.log or error.log - which makes this extra difficult.

I followed their directions to the T, the user I'm using for WSGIDaemonProcess is just the standard AWS user, ubuntu

Not really sure where I went wrong, all I know is that I can get it working using `tracd`.

Here is my `/sites-available/bloodhound` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   WSGIDaemonProcess bh_tracker user=ubuntu python-path=/home/bloodhound/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   WSGIScriptAlias /bloodhound /home/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/bloodhound/site/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
   <Directory /home/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/bloodhound/site/cgi-bin>
     WSGIProcessGroup bh_tracker
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
   <LocationMatch "/bloodhound/[^/]+/login">
     AuthType Digest
     AuthName "Bloodhound"
     AuthDigestDomain /bloodhound
     AuthUserFile /home/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/bloodhound/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest
     Require valid-user
   </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Nothing else really needs to be configured except for PostgreSQL, which is simple enough and I know is working since the dev server won't work without it.

I have my AWS security groups set up to allow traffic on those ports as well.

Glad to give more info

Comment: Well, for one thing your port is 8000 but your VirtualHost is 8080.

Comment: How did you fix this ?