# Configuring the apache bloodhound's website

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

My question is very close to this one: [Apache bloodhound installation, AWS host not serving site](https://serverfault.com/questions/556174/apache-bloodhound-installation-aws-host-not-serving-site)

I get nothing in the access log, nothing in the error log, the browser is saying:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8000
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall#Usersandfilelocations

My configuration file is (I've placed it in: /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
   WSGIDaemonProcess bh_tracker user=bloodhound python-path=/opt/bloodhound/bhenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   WSGIScriptAlias /bloodhound /opt/bloodhound/environments/main/site/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
   <Directory /opt/bloodhound/environments/main/site/cgi-bin>
     WSGIProcessGroup bh_tracker
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
   <LocationMatch "/bloodhound/[^/]+/login">
     AuthType Digest
     AuthName "Bloodhound"
     AuthDigestDomain /bloodhound
     AuthUserFile /opt/bloodhound/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest
     Require valid-user
   </LocationMatch>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Every folder/file in it exsists.
I have followed all the steppes in the tutorial, I can run the bloodhound if I do this:

```
 tracd --port=8000 /opt/bloodhound/environments/main
```

Any suggestions are gladly appreciated since I have ran out of ideas.

When I try to activate the site:

> sudo a2ensite bloodhound.conf
>   Site bloodhound already enabled

Comment: Did you actually install it in your localhost or did you install it on a remote server?

Comment: What does the `Listen` directive in the main `httpd.conf` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there were 2 issues. The first one was that apache wasn't listening to the port. This needed to be added to the `ports.con`f file.

The second error was that the folder wasn't configured in the `apache.conf` 
A new entry had to be made there for this folder.

After that it worked.